# How to implement a circular buffer using a file?

Tags: c, file-io, embedded

My application (C program) opens two file handles to the same file (one in write and one in read mode). Two separate threads in the app read from and write to the file. This works fine. 
Since my app runs on embedded device with a limited ram disk size, I would like write `FileHandle` to wrap to beginning of file on reaching max size and the read `FileHandle` to follow like a circular buffer. I understand from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741888/read-and-write-from-a-file-in-a-circular-buffer-fashion) that this should work. However as soon as I do `fseek` of write `FileHandle` to beginning of file, `fread` returns error. Will the `EOF` get reset on doing `fseek` to beginning of file? If so, which function should be used to cause write file position to get set to 0 without causing `EOF` to be reset.

EDIT/UPDATE:
I tried couple of things:

---

1. Based on @neodelphi I used pipes this works. However my usecase requires I write to a file. I receive multiple channels of live video surveilance stream that needs to be stored to harddisk and also read back decoded and displayed on monitor.
2. Thanks to @Clement suggestions on doing ftell I fixed a couple of bugs in my code and wrap works for the reader however, the data read appears to be stale data since write are still buffered but reader reads stale content from hard disk. I cant avoid buffering due to performance considerations (I get 32Mbps of live data that needs to be written to harddisk). I have tried things like flushing writes only in the interval from when write wraps to when read wraps and truncating the file (ftruncate)  after read wraps but this doesnt solve the stale data problem.
3. I am trying to use two files in ping-pong fashion to see if this solves the issue but want to know if there is a better solution

Comment: Are you locking while reading-writing the file ?

Comment: If you're developping on a linux-like system, did you tries pipe files ? These kind of files only stores what have been written but not read, so implementing a circular buffer may not be necessary.

Comment: @Clement. I am not having any locks . I use std C lib fread and fwrite calls

Comment: If you use them on the same file handle, there _will_ be trouble. Is that the case ?

Comment: @Clement. I do fopen twice and have two separate file handles (one in read mode and one in write mode) to the same physical file.Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157234/) is not quite a duplicate, but is very close.

Comment: @neodelphi. Thank you for the suggestion. I wasnt aware of pipe files . As you mentioned this will eliminate the need to have circular buffer which is very good. I will try it out

Comment: @Clement Thank you the debugging tip.I have edited the original question with additional details

Comment: according to http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/node27.html , there should be no influence between two file handles position opened in different modes (a least on an UNIX system). Could you post some runnable code ? Maybe it's a small logical error.

Comment: What platform is this for? All that is said is that it's an embedded device - that can range from a full-blown Linux system down to something with no OS at all and a simple runtime layer on top of some device drivers.

Comment: @Michael This is a TI816X platform running linux on cortex A8. http://software-dl.ti.com/trainingTTO/trainingTTO_public_sw/netra1day/netra1day.html

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like that :

```
// Write
if(ftell(WriteHandle)>BUFFER_MAX) rewind (WriteHandle);
fwrite(WriteHandle,/* ... */);

// Read (assuming binary)
readSize = fread (buffer,1,READ_CHUNK_SIZE,ReadHandle);
if(readSize!=READ_CHUNK_SIZE){
    rewind (ReadHandle);
    if(fread (buffer+readSize,1,READ_CHUNK_SIZE-readSize,ReadHandle)!=READ_CHUNK_SIZE-readSize)
        ;// ERROR !
}
```

Not tested, but it gives an idea. The write should also handle the case `BUFFER_MAX` is not modulo `WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE`.

Also, you may read only if you are sure that the data has already been written. But I guess you already do that.

Comment: Below is my code. Similar to what you have except I use fseek instead of rewind.`     fpos = ftell(fp);if ((fpos + bytesToWrite) >= maxFileSize){fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);} `

Comment: @Bardi fread don't just return error, it returns a number. What number ? What does `feof()` return ? Also, `feof()` is reset on fseek, rewind and clearerr ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/clearerr/ ).

Comment: On write wrap, I set the wrap position in a shared variable (with mutex protection) . When read position reaches this wrap position I do rewind of Read File Handle even before doing fread. So I would expect no errors to occur. I get fread errors as soon as write wraps around even though read position has not reached the wrap point yet. The read will always been same size as write chunk size in my app

Comment: Could you try to make a ftell on read failure ? That may help to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could mmap the file into you're virtual memory and then just create a normal circular buffer with the pointer returned.

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
volatile void * mem = mmap(NULL, max_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
volatile char * c_mem = (volatile char *)mem;
c_mem[index % max_size] = 'a'; // This line will now write to the offset index in the file 
// Now doing
```

Can also probably be stricter on permissions depending on on exact case.